# How to publish artifact archive files from jenkins to a local directory on centos using naming of build number and repository

Tags: svn, jenkins, centos

I have managed to install Jenkins and set it up to build artifact archive files, but the names of these files are called archive.zip

I would like to publish to a local directory on my centos server, which will have sub directories for the tag name/number, and on the archive files they will be named using a date/time string and a build/revision number.

Can anyone point me out in the right direction for how to achieve this please?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin

or

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+...

If the renaming of the artifact not clearly supported, consider naming the parent directories with jobname, version, etc.